how to interpret that for each batch the same class is predicted
I am trying to implement an action recognition model, using a Transformer. Basically, it is based on a spatial transformer  which takes joints as input and temporal one which takes the output of the first model (cls token). For training each batch is almost predicted the same, for example:
predictions:  tensor([30,  2, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30])
predictions:  tensor([58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58])
predictions:  tensor([36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36])
predictions:  tensor([53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53])
predictions:  tensor([58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58])
predictions:  tensor([30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30])
predictions:  tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
predictions:  tensor([41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41])
predictions:  tensor([20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20])
predictions:  tensor([17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17])
predictions:  tensor([34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34])
predictions:  tensor([13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13])
predictions:  tensor([12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12])
predictions:  tensor([43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43])
predictions:  tensor([24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24])
predictions:  tensor([18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18])
predictions:  tensor([35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35])
predictions:  tensor([15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15])
predictions:  tensor([45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45])
predictions:  tensor([38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38])
predictions:  tensor([46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46])
predictions:  tensor([11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11])
predictions:  tensor([27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27])
predictions:  tensor([41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41])
predictions:  tensor([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
predictions:  tensor([50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50])

Is it a comman result espacially for first epochs or something is going wrong (which i think it is the case). I share also the main class
class ActRecogTransformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device='cpu', mocap_frames=100, num_joints=50, in_chans=3, spatial_embed=64, sdepth=4, tdepth=4,
                 num_heads=8, mlp_ratio=2., qkv_bias=True, qk_scale=None, op_type='cls', embed_type='conv',
                 drop_rate=0., attn_drop_rate=0., drop_path_rate=0.2, norm_layer=None, num_classes=60):
        super().__init__()

        #Spatial patch and pos embeddings
        if embed_type=='lin':
            self.Spatial_patch_to_embedding = nn.Linear(in_chans, spatial_embed)#Linear patch embedding
        else:
            self.Spatial_patch_to_embedding = nn.Conv1d(in_chans, spatial_embed, 1, 1)#Conv patch embedding


        self.Spatial_pos_embed = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, num_joints+1, spatial_embed))
        self.spat_token = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1,1,spatial_embed))
        self.proj_up_clstoken = nn.Linear(mocap_frames*spatial_embed, num_joints*spatial_embed)
        self.sdepth = sdepth
        self.num_joints = num_joints

        #Temporal embedding
        norm_layer = norm_layer or partial(nn.LayerNorm, eps=1e-6)
        temp_embed = spatial_embed * (num_joints)
        temp_frames = mocap_frames
        acc_embed = temp_embed
        self.op_type = op_type
        self.embed_type = embed_type
        self.Temporal_pos_embed = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, temp_frames+1, temp_embed)) #additional pos embedding zero for class token
        self.temp_frames = mocap_frames
        self.joint_coords = in_chans



        sdpr = [x.item() for x in torch.linspace(0, drop_path_rate, sdepth)]  #Stochastic depth decay rule
        tdpr = [x.item() for x in torch.linspace(0, drop_path_rate, tdepth)]  #Stochastic depth decay rule
      

        self.Spatial_blocks = nn.ModuleList([
            Block(
                dim=spatial_embed, num_heads=num_heads, mlp_ratio=mlp_ratio, qkv_bias=qkv_bias, qk_scale=qk_scale,
                drop=drop_rate, attn_drop=attn_drop_rate, drop_path=sdpr[i], norm_layer=norm_layer)
            for i in range(sdepth)])

        self.Temporal_blocks = nn.ModuleList([
            Block(
                dim=temp_embed, num_heads=num_heads, mlp_ratio=mlp_ratio, qkv_bias=qkv_bias, qk_scale=qk_scale,
                drop=drop_rate, attn_drop=attn_drop_rate, drop_path=tdpr[i], norm_layer=norm_layer)
            for i in range(tdepth)])



        self.Spatial_norm = norm_layer(spatial_embed)
        self.Temporal_norm = norm_layer(temp_embed)

        self.pos_drop = nn.Dropout(p=drop_rate)
                #Classification head
        self.class_head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LayerNorm(temp_embed),
            nn.Linear(temp_embed, num_classes)
        )



    def forward(self, x, dims = 3):
        #x = self.pes(x)

        b, f, p, c = x.shape  # b is batch size, f is number of frames, p is number of joints, c is in_chan 3


        x = rearrange(x, 'b f p c  -> (b f) p c', )  # 4, 100, 50, 3 => 400,50,3
        if self.embed_type == 'conv':
            x = rearrange(x, '(b f) p c  -> (b f) c p',b=b ) # b x 3 x Fa  - Conv k liye channels first,, 400,3,50
            x = self.Spatial_patch_to_embedding(x) # B x c x p ->  B x Se x p
            x = rearrange(x, '(b f) Se p  -> (b f) p Se', b=b)
        else:
            x = self.Spatial_patch_to_embedding(x) # B x p x c ->  B x p x Se

        # (1,1,spatial_embed which is 32) for spat_token size and the results is (400,1,32)
        class_token=torch.tile(self.spat_token,(b*f,1,1)) # (B,1,1)
        x = torch.cat((x,class_token),dim=1) # b x (p+1) x Se
        x += self.Spatial_pos_embed
        #x = self.pes(x)
        x = self.pos_drop(x)


        # Spatial transformer
        #x = self.spatial_encoder(x)
        for blk in self.Spatial_blocks:
            x = blk(x)
        x = self.Spatial_norm(x)

        Se = x.shape[-1]
        #cls_token = x[:,0]
        cls_token = x[:,-1,:]

        cls_token = torch.reshape(cls_token, (b,f*Se)) #4, 100*32
        x = x[:,:p,:]
        x = rearrange(x, '(b f) p Se-> b f (p Se)', f=f)


        # Temporal transformer
        b,f,St = x.shape
     #   x = self.pet(x)


        b  = x.shape[0]
        temp_cls_token = self.proj_up_clstoken(cls_token) #in: B x mocap_frames * Se -> op: B x num_joints*Se
        temp_cls_token = torch.unsqueeze(temp_cls_token,dim=1) #op: B x 1 x num_joints*Se

        x = torch.cat((x,temp_cls_token), dim=1) #B x mocap_frames +1 x temp_embed | temp_embed = num_joints*Se

        x += self.Temporal_pos_embed
       # x = self.pet(x)
        x = self.pos_drop(x)
       # x = self.temporal_encoder(x)
      #  print(x.shape)
        for blk in self.Temporal_blocks:
            x = blk(x)

        x = self.Temporal_norm(x)

        ###Extract Class token head from the output
        if self.op_type=='cls':
            #cls_token = x[:,0]
            cls_token = x[:,-1,:]
            cls_token = cls_token.view(b, -1) # (Batch_size, temp_embed)
            x = self.class_head(cls_token)


        else:
            x = x[:,:f,:]
            x = rearrange(x, 'b f St -> b St f')
            x = F.avg_pool1d(x,x.shape[-1],stride=x.shape[-1]) #b x St x 1
            x = torch.reshape(x, (b,St))
        # Classification head...

        return (x)



For training:
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        correct=0
        total=0
        running_loss = 0.0
        epoch_loss = 0.0
        L = []
#        for i in range(steps):
        for i, data_ in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
            # Get the input sequences and their corresponding targets
            inputs, targets = data_
            #x, y = X_train[i*batch_size:(i*batch_size)+batch_size], y_train[i*batch_size:(i*batch_size)+batch_size]
            #inputs, targets = torch.from_numpy(inputs).to(device), torch.from_numpy(targets).to(device)
            inputs, targets = (inputs).to(device),(targets).to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            predictions = model(inputs.float())
            targets = targets.long()
            print("predictions: ",torch.max(predictions, 1) )

            loss = criterion(predictions, targets)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            #print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %(epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss ))
            running_loss = 0.0
            y_pred_softmax = torch.log_softmax(predictions.data, dim = 1)
            _, predicted = torch.max(y_pred_softmax, 1)
            total += targets.size(0)
            correct += (predicted ==targets).sum().item()
            # print("predicted",torch.max(y_pred_softmax, 1))
            # print("targets", targets.long())
        accuracy = 100 * correct / total
        epoch_loss = epoch_loss / steps
        print("Training Accuracy = {} : Training Loss {}".format(accuracy,epoch_loss))

I tried also to use TransformerEncoder instead of Block clas, but i am still getting the same. Is it a common behavior, for maybe the first 3, 4 epochs, still getting very bad accuracy no more than 2%.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
